# Jest Testing in React Native (EXPO) .jsx extension not working "React.createElement: type is invalid"

Tags: react-native, jestjs, babeljs, expo, babel-jest

## Issue

I'm trying to test using jest, but it looks like my compiler is not handling .jsx files. If I change both of the files extension to js: (**App.jsx** and **App.test.jsx**) to (**App.JS** and **App.test.JS**), it does work. But I want to be able to use jsx files.

## Files

[image: folder structure]

## App.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

## App.test.jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
// import { render } from '@testing-library/react-native';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

import App from './App';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(<App />).toJSON();
  expect(tree.children.length).toBe(1);

  // const { toJSON } = render(<App />); // ** THIS DOESN'T WORK EITHER **
  // expect(toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

## Console Error

**Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.**

[image]

## package.json

```json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "test": "jest --watch",
    "test:debug": "jest",
    "test:coverage": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll",
    "test:pr": "npm test -- coverage --ci --silent --changedSince=origin/development --coverageReporters='text' --coverageReporters='lcov'",
    "test:all": "npm test -- --coverage --ci --silent --watchAll=false",
    "linter": "eslint src",
    "linter:fix": "eslint src --fix"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "i18next": "^20.2.2",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "msw": "^0.28.2",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-41.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.14.2",
    "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.13.16",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^7.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.23",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.23.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest-expo": "^41.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|\\.(test|spec))\\.(js|jsx)$",
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "jsx"
    ],
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "setupFiles": [
      "./jestSetup.js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure Jest to accept jsx extensions. This is done in the jest section of your package.json file or in your jest.config.js file (if you have both Jest seems to ignore the package.json contents).

Take a look at this: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/setting-up-jest-under-expo-to-work-with-jsx-files-ba35a51bc25a

Here's what worked for me:

```
$ yarn add --dev babel-jest@latest
```

then in package.json:

```
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!((jest-)?react-native|@react-native(-community)?)|expo(nent)?|@expo(nent)?/.*|@expo-google-fonts/.*|react-navigation|@react-navigation/.*|@unimodules/.*|unimodules|sentry-expo|native-base|react-native-svg)"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.[jt]sx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }
```